# Trouble with rank or rownum with SQL window function

Tags: sql-server, function, rank

The output I would like from the data below should look like this:

```
   id   empid   question            type    rownum
  1      75     How old are you     SSS       1
  2      75     NULL                LLL       2
  3      88     How old are you     SSS       1
  4      88     NULL                LLL       2
  5      99     How old are you     SSS       1
  6      99     How old are you     LLL       1
  7      99     NULL                LLL       2
```

My desired output is if there is an empid that has both SSS and LLL types, but the LLL question is null, then only return the SSS record.  There can be instances where an empid has both SSS and LLL types with the question, but also containing a second LLL type with a null question.  In the end I will only bring back those records with a rownum = 1.

```
    declare @t table(id int, empid int, question varchar(250), type char(3))
    insert into @t values( 1, 75, 'How old are you', 'SSS'),
                  (2, 75, NULL, 'LLL'),
                  (3, 88, 'How old are you', 'SSS'),
                  (4, 88, NULL, 'LLL'),
                  (5, 99, 'How old are you', 'SSS'),
                  (6, 99, 'How old are you', 'LLL'),
                  (7, 99, NULL, 'LLL')
```

I wrote the following query, which is close, but I cannot get the exact result I'm looking for as it is assigning a rownum = 2 for both 'LLL' types for empid = 99.

```
   select *,
   rank()over(partition by empid order by type desc,
   case when question is not null and type = 'LLL' then 1 else 2 end desc) as rownum
   from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
     select *,
     dense_rank()over(partition by empid, case when question is not null and type = 
     'LLL' then 1 else 2 end order by type desc
      ) as rownum
       from @t
```